# How to initialize a static string array in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to declare an array to store my strings as follows.

```
bytes32[3] verifiedResult;
verifiedResult = ["verified successfully", "verified failed", "not clear"];
```

Error shows that

```
ParserError: Expected identifier but got '=' --> contracts/1_Storage.sol:23:20: | 23 | verifiedResult = ["verified_successfully", "verified_failed", "not clear"] |^
```

what should I do to fix it? Is there any better way to declare a static string array in solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string` keyword, or in your case, a fixed-sized (3) array of strings.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract MyContract {
    // string in storage
    string[3] verifiedResult = ["verified successfully", "verified failed", "not clear"];
    
    function foo() external {
        // string in memory
        string[3] memory anotherStringArray = ["verified successfully", "verified failed", "not clear"];
    }
}
```

---

Also, your copy looks like you can use [enum](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#enums).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract MyContract {
    enum VerifiedResult {VerifiedSuccessfully, VerifiedFailed, NotClear}
    
    VerifiedResult result;
    
    function foo() external {
        result = VerifiedResult.NotClear; // stores `NotClear` to the `result` property
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `enum` is a  very good opinion. But I want to show a string on the screen which means that I need to return a string. can I return a static string just like this `return verfiedResult[0]`?

Comment: Yes, you can expand the first snippet and return string like this: `function foo() external returns (string memory) { return verifiedResult[0]; }`